# Select a value from a specific column and row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm storing the result of a SQL Query in a DataFrame and I just don't understand how can I get a specific value. I have the following code:

```
    for date in years:
    partyList = pd.read_sql_query(
        "SELECT top 2 country_name,election_date,party_name_english, vote_share, left_right FROM view_election WHERE country_name_short like '" + country + "' and election_date like '" + date + "' ORDER BY vote_share DESC",
        conn)
    parties = str(partyList).replace(" ", "").split()
    parties.remove(parties[0])
    format(parties)
    # print(partyList)
    total = total.append(partyList)
print(total.iloc[0, 0:1])
```

The output is:

```
country_name    Slovakia
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

**How can I get the String "Slovakia" to a variable? I want to understand how I do it so I can use it for other values as well**

Also, How can I store an entire row into a "normal" array? I'm asking this just because I find it easier to work with regular arrays

Comment: change the print statement to this print(`total.iloc[0, 0:1].values[0]`)

Comment: You are right, thank you! By the way, can you help with the second question?

Comment: `list(df.iloc[0].values)` gets you the 0th row as a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total.iloc[0, 0:1]` selects a slice of columns at row 0. If you only want the entry at `[0,0]`, either use integer-location based indexing `iloc`:

```
total.iloc[0, 0]
```

or label based indexing `loc`:

```
total.loc[0, 'country_name']
```

If you want to store a row (for example the first row) into an array, you can first index it, then use `to_numpy` method to convert to array:

```
arr = total.iloc[0].to_numpy()
```